# Рабочий дискорд бот вдруг перестал выполнять команды. В чем причина?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

У меня был довольно большой код, который нормально работал и мне его хватало. Этого бота я оставил месяца на 2 и не пользовался им, после чего снова запустил, а он практически ни на что не реагирует. Ниже я представил отдельные части этого кода, но из всех команд он только пытается скопировать сообщение в другой чат, но записывает туда только имя отправителя без самого текста. Что могло произойти и как это исправить? Пытался переприглашать, выдавать разные роли и права, но ничего не помогло.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle

TOKEN = "Тут мой токен"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=('.'))
client.remove_command( 'help' )


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    DiscordComponents(client)
    print("Я запущен!")

@client.command()
async def send(ctx):
     await ctx.author.send ('Привет')

@client.command( pass_context = True )
async def clear( ctx, amount = 1000 ):
 await ctx.channel.purge( limit = amount)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

   if message.channel.id == 983379775836008500:
       embed = discord.Embed(
           description=f'{message.content}\nАвтор: {message.author}',
           color=0xFF0033
       )

       await client.get_channel(983410250520604733).send(embed=embed)


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: может что-то в логах есть, может он на что-то ругается?..

Comment: Неа. Такое чувство. словно он просто не видит команду. Я выяснил, что это возможно из-за изменений связанных с intents, но как с ними работать я не понял

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте после импорта вот эти строчки:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
```

Затем зайдите на discord.com/developers и выберите Вашего бота. Затем зайдите в раздел **Bot** и поставьте галочку на **"MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT Required for your bot to receive message content in most messages"**

Бот будет работать на серверах. Сейчас он у Вас работает только в личных сообщениях.

Причина в том, что дискорд изменил возможности не верифицированных ботов, перешёл на API 10. Если у Вас крупный бот на более 100 серверах, то придётся переходить на / команды.